# Unable to create cluster in AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I was trying to create an EMR cluster from Eclipse using Java. I was able to output the job id but when I viewed the EMR web console. There wasn't any cluster created. What's wrong ?

My code:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxx", "xxx");
         AmazonElasticMapReduceClient emr = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

            StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();

            StepConfig enableDebugging = new StepConfig()
                .withName("Enable Debugging")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newEnableDebuggingStep());

            StepConfig installHive = new StepConfig()
                .withName("Install Hive")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newInstallHiveStep());

            StepConfig hiveScript = new StepConfig().withName("Hive Script")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newRunHiveScriptStep("s3://mywordcountbuckett/binary/WordCount2.jar"));

            RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
                .withName("Hive Interactive")
                .withReleaseLabel("emr-4.1.0")
                .withSteps(enableDebugging, installHive)
                .withJobFlowRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
                .withServiceRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
                //.withSteps(enableDebugging, installHive)
                .withLogUri("s3://mywordcountbuckett/")
                .withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                    .withEc2KeyName("mykeypair")
                    .withHadoopVersion("2.4.0")            
                    .withInstanceCount(5)
                    .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)
                    .withMasterInstanceType("m3.xlarge")
                    .withSlaveInstanceType("m1.large"));//.withAmiVersion("3.10.0");

            RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request);
            System.out.println(result.toString());
```

My output was:

```
{JobFlowId: j-3T7H65FOSKHDQ}
```

What could be the reason that I was unable to create the cluster ?

Comment: What credentials did you use for creating this cluster - IAM or Root? And how did you login to EMR Console - IAM or Root login?

Comment: i used IAM to create the cluster. I login from the web interface aws.amazon.com @vidit

Comment: The cluster is created, and there can be multiple reasons why it's not showing up on EMR Console. The best guess is "VisibleToAllUsers" flag which is set to false for this cluster.

Comment: Did you use the same IAM user for creating the cluster and login to EMR Console?